# Oauth: Where to set oauth_callback?

Tags: scala, oauth, playframework, dropbox, playframework-2.0

I'm having a problem understanding the OAuth 1.0 specification.

The oauth Authentication has 3 steps:

1. get request_token (server <-> server)
2. redirect user and authorize (client is redirected)
3. exchange request_token for access_token (server <-> server)

I want to set an oauth_callback, so the user gets redirected to my site in step 2.

Considering https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-2.1 I have to put the oauth_callback parameter in step 1.

Considering http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#auth_step2 I have to put it in step 2.

What is correct?

The dropbox oauth documentation says its step 2: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api

But the play framework (scala web framework) implementation sends this parameter in step 1.

This results in my web application not redirecting the user back to my site after authentication.

But which implementation is wrong? Dropbox or Play? Or am I completely mistaking something and both are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a different OAuth version.

- OAuth 1.0 specifies the parameter in step 2
- OAuth 1.0a specifies the parameter in step 1

The RFC was updated for 1.0a whereas http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#auth_step2 is for the 1.0 version. There is a new document for 1.0a (http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/)